# Setting the connection pool (and other database options) using Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

From this page, it looks like Heroku does most of the work in building your `database.yml` file on deployment, meaning that all I have to have is my `development` and `test` environment configurations.

Is there a way I can also specify `production` values? For example, if I wanted to set `pool: 25` on `production`, can I include that in my `database.yml` as follows?

```
development: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_app_development
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  min_messages: warning
  pool: 2
  timeout: 5000

test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_test

-- Can I add this, or will it get overwritten?
production:
  <<: *default
  pool: 25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, found the answer to exactly my question on the Heroku documentation

https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/426

Looks like whatever options you set will be merged in and preserved, so I can indeed set connection pool in my `database.yml`